# Askbot installation - TemplateSyntaxError at /questions/ Invalid block tag: 'import'

Tags: python, django, askbot

I am totally new to askbot-django-python. please help me.

I used a guide available at askbot.org to install askbot 0.10.0 in Ubuntu 15.10 server. During installation, after runserver command, when I try to access the site from remote computer, subject error message get displayed.I spent entire day to figure it out but unable to. please help me

details appended below:

> Request Method:    GET
>
> Request URL:   http://212.222.47.4:8000/questions/
>
> Django Version:    1.7
>
> Exception Type:    TemplateSyntaxError
>
> Exception Value:   Invalid block tag: 'import'
>
> Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 344
>
> Python Executable:     /usr/bin/python
>
> Python Version:    2.7.10
>
> Python Path:   '/var/www/html/askbot/public_html',
>
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_debug_toolbar-1.4-py2.7.egg',
>
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_openid-2.2.5-py2.7.egg',
>
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_filter-0.5.4-py2.7.egg',
>
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_haystack-1.2.0-py2.7.egg',
>
> '/usr/lib/python2.7',
>
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
>
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
>
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
>
> '/var/www/html/askbot',
>
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/askbot/deps']
>
> Server time:   Sat, 2 Jan 2016 07:29:04 -0600

The traceback is appended below:

> Traceback:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>
>   111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/askbot/views/readers.py" in questions
>
>   287.         return render(request, 'main_page.html', template_data)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
>
>   48.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
>
>   170.         t = get_template(template_name, dirs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
>
>   144.     template, origin = find_template(template_name, dirs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
>
>   132.             source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in **call**
>
>   44.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in load_template
>
>   50.             template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template_from_string
>
>   156.     return Template(source, origin, name)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in **init**
>
>   132.         self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_string
>
>   162.     return parser.parse()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
>
>   290.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in do_extends
>
>   201.     nodelist = parser.parse()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
>
>   288.                     self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in invalid_block_tag
>
>   344.         raise self.error(token, "Invalid block tag: '%s'" % command)
>
> Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /questions/
>
> Exception Value: Invalid block tag: 'import'

Comment: Let's see the template file for /questions/

Comment: Seems like it's using the [Jinja2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2) template engine, DTL doesn't have an `{% import %}` tag.

Comment: Onyeka - Thank you. are you referring to question.html located at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/askbot/templates/?

Comment: knbk - Thank you. but what should i do to resolve the issue? should i install Jinja2 template engine separately? I installed askbot, per guide available at [install askbot in ubuntu](http://askbot.org/doc/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, into second day, **upgraded django to 1.8**. The issue got resolved, though not sure what was the root cause.

Per askbot documentation, 0.10.0 supports only django 1.7. However upgrading to 1.8, resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when your TEMPLATES settings.py value is the default `django-admin startproject` value, askbot has a specific override that you can see if thier setup_templates

> https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/blob/master/askbot/setup_templates/settings.py#L76-L91